# Change phone/desktop transition width cutoff for responsive Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'd like to change the "cutoff" width (currently 767px) at which Bootstrap changes from small-desktop mode (i.e. grid elements in a row are still horizontally placed) to phone mode (i.e. grid elements in a row are placed on top of each other and fill the screen width). Specifically, Bootstrap uses queries like `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)`. It seems that the 767 and 768 are hard-coded into the LESS source code, though. Is there a supported way to do this, or will I just have to make the changes manually and hope it doesn't break anything?

EDIT: Yes, I know that Twitter chose these values for a reason... it just strikes me as odd that seemingly everything else in the framework is modular and customizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the ***responsive*** part of Bootstrap. I would not load bootstrap-responsive and load my own ones. Everything is defined in `responsive*.less` files.

Comment: I was hoping for a more straightforward solution, but after reading through the source of those files, it does seem like find-replacing those values is the best I can do. If I get around to it, I'll send Twitter a pull request making those values more easily configurable.

Answer (score 2):

The LESS value you look for is

```
@grid-float-breakpoint: 123px;
```